# Reused Cells in UITableView Cause Unwanted Actions to Occur

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I couldn't find an answer online, nor could I phrase the question properly without knowing the exact problem.

I used to have a tableview that has "a custom UIView subview that contains a subview UIButton in x:2, y:2 coordinates", and that subview UIButton has a blank star image that switches to a filled up star image upon user's touch.

Image1:
[image: Image1]

Image2: 
[image: Image2]

It used to work fine, until I touched the code a bit here and there.

The problem that occurs now is that when I touch the button in row 1, for example, the star fills up in row 1, but also in row 13. The pictures above are the results of a single touch on the star next to "Acetate" row.
Funnily enough, when the device changes to iPad Air 2, or any device with other screen size, the responding cells change (for example, row 1 responds with row 22).

I've been receiving comments from other people that the problem originates from cells being reused, but I lack understanding of UITableViewCell to know what is going on. I understand that dynamic cells are reused, but does that mean that certain cells are clones of each other?

The codes are as follows:

```
class WordListTableViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var starButtonView: StarButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //setting the wordList of wordListObject


    ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList.sortInPlace()

    ChemQuizCollection.formulaImages.sortInPlace()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 25
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordListTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordListTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.starButtonView.buttonRow = row

    cell.formulaLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.formulaLabel.text = ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList[row]
    cell.formulaImage.image = UIImage(named: ChemQuizCollection.formulaImages[row])


    if (FavoritesManager.favoritesList.objectForKey("\(row)") != nil) {
        cell.starButtonView.buttonSelected = true
    }


    return cell
}
```

And

```
class StarButton: UIView {

var buttonRow : Int = 0
var buttonSelected : Bool = false

override init (frame : CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
    initStar()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initStar()
}

func initStar() {

    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 33, height: 33))

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StarButton.fillingStar(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)

    if buttonSelected == true {
        button.selected = true
    }

    addSubview(button)
}

//Could have various errors
func fillingStar(sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.selected) == false {
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.setObject(ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList[buttonRow], forKey: "\(buttonRow)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.synchronize()
    } else {
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.removeObjectForKey("\(buttonRow)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.synchronize()
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    for view in subviews
    {
        view.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

And

```
struct FavoritesManager {
     static var favoritesList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

     static func resetFavorites() {
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
     }

}
```

Thank you all in advance. School's starting soon, and this problem's been nagging me for a week, so I'm kind of desperate for any help :). If anyone could leave a way for me to continuously ask him questions, I would be genuinely grateful.

Comment: I know that my code is messy (I am a real beginner). If the question is unanswerable due to my lack of coding skills, I'm happy to receive suggestions as to how to make it more legible. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UITableViewCells are reused - that means that you have limited amount of cell - and when one cell is going off from screen, the another cell, that now is currently invisible, is going to the screen, using `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` 
 In your case, you should use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method for trigger state changing of cell, and responds to this changes 
 Generally, you should avoid using button in cells, when it's really inevitable 
 
 Hope this may help

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your explanation was exactly what I didn't understand about tableview...now I at least know what's causing the problem :) Thank you again.

Comment: @Daniel, don't forget to mark as resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem you need to set the star icon to its default state if the button is not selected within cellForRowAtIndexPath. i.e. the cell that is being reused needs to be set with the star in its default state.

You are maintaining a list of selected cells, therefore when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, all the selected cells should be set with their star icon highlighted and all other cells should be set with the default icon.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     ...

     if (FavoritesManager.favoritesList.objectForKey("\(row)") != nil) {
          cell.starButtonView.buttonSelected = true
     } else {
          cell.starButtonView.buttonSelected = false
     }

     ...
}
```

Inside your star view containing the button, you need to set the button to be deselected based on what you have set in the above method.

```
class StarButton: UIView {
...

     func initStar(){
          ...

          if buttonSelected == true {
              button.selected = true
          } else { 
              button.selected = false
          }

          ...
     }   
...  

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try out your suggestions. I finally feel like I'm grasping something here.

Comment: @Daniel Remember to mark the question as resolved if this solved your issue.